# Client Specific Localization

Tags: asp.net, localization

Looking for advice for this tricky kind(for me!) of localization.
We have different client in our project and we are making localization for client wise.
Condition if client specific resx file is not available then it should take the default resx language wise.

We have folder structure like this :-

LocalizationFolder

en-us folder

Client1Folder :-
       en-us client specific resx file

default resx file

We have tried using getglobalresourceobject and getlocalresourceobject methods. These methods will go to till the last/deepest path in folder structure. But it is not picking up the client specific resx file. 
We have kept naming convention of resx file same for default and client specific resx file.

Thats why it giving error as 'default.en-us.resx file already exist OR it conflicts with other file'.

So my question how can i pick up the resx file based on client name and if it is not present the pick up the default resx file.

Is this possible Or any different approach needs to be follow.

Comment: Any suggestions on this problem ??

Comment: Can you add a screen capture of your current resource structure?